# Imap is not fetching the body of the mail?

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap, incoming-mail

Am using Imap to fetch the mails from gmail. If am sending any mails manually, am able to receive the body of the mail but If I kept auto forward from some other mail to my mail, then am unable to receive to body. May I know what is the problem in my code and here are my code

```
<?class Imap {
private $imapStream;
private $plaintextMessage;
private $htmlMessage;
private $emails;
private $errors = array();
private $attachments = array();
private $attachments_dir = 'attachments/';
private $limit = 10;
public function connect($hostname, $username, $password) {
    $connection = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail: ' . imap_last_error());
    if (!preg_match("/Resource.id.*/", (string) $connection)) {
        return $connection; //return error message
    }
    $this->imapStream = $connection;
    return true;
}
public function getMessages($type = 'text') {
    $stream = $this->imapStream;
    $emails = imap_search($stream, 'ALL');
    $messages = array();
    if ($emails) {
        $this->emails = $emails;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
            $this->attachments = array();
            $uid = imap_uid($stream, $email_number);
            $messages[] = $this->loadMessage($uid, $type);
            if ($i == $this->limit) {
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $messages;
}
public function deletemail($uid) {
    $delete = imap_delete($this->imapStream, $uid);
}
private function loadMessage($uid, $type) {
    $overview = $this->getOverview($uid);
    $array = array();
    $array['subject'] = isset($overview->subject) ? $this->decode($overview->subject) : '';
    $array['date'] = strtotime($overview->date);
    $array['message_id'] = $overview->message_id;
    $array['uid'] = $overview->uid;
    $array['references'] = isset($overview->references) ? $overview->references : 0;
    $headers = $this->getHeaders($uid);
    $array['from'] = isset($headers->from) ? $this->processAddressObject($headers->from) : array('');
    $structure = $this->getStructure($uid);
    if (!isset($structure->parts)) { // not multipart
        $this->processStructure($uid, $structure);
    } else { // multipart
        foreach ($structure->parts as $id => $part) {
            $this->processStructure($uid, $part, $id + 1);
        }
    }
    $array['message'] = $type == 'text' ? $this->plaintextMessage : $this->htmlMessage;
    $array['attachments'] = $this->attachments;
    return $array;
}
private function processStructure($uid, $structure, $partIdentifier = null) {
    $parameters = $this->getParametersFromStructure($structure);
    if ((isset($parameters['name']) || isset($parameters['filename'])) || (isset($structure->subtype) && strtolower($structure->subtype) == 'rfc822')
    ) {
        if (isset($parameters['filename'])) {
            $this->setFileName($parameters['filename']);
        } elseif (isset($parameters['name'])) {
            $this->setFileName($parameters['name']);
        }
        $this->encoding = $structure->encoding;
        $result_save = $this->saveToDirectory($this->attachments_dir, $uid, $partIdentifier);
        if ($result_save === true) {
            $this->attachments[] = $this->filename;
        }
    } elseif ($structure->type == 0 || $structure->type == 1) {
        $messageBody = isset($partIdentifier) ?
                imap_fetchbody($this->imapStream, $uid, $partIdentifier, FT_UID | FT_PEEK) : imap_body($this->imapStream, $uid, FT_UID | FT_PEEK);
        $messageBody = $this->decodeMessage($messageBody, $structure->encoding);
        if (!empty($parameters['charset']) && $parameters['charset'] !== 'UTF-8') {
            if (function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
                if (!in_array($parameters['charset'], mb_list_encodings())) {
                    if ($structure->encoding === 0) {
                        $parameters['charset'] = 'US-ASCII';
                    } else {
                        $parameters['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
                    }
                }
                $messageBody = mb_convert_encoding($messageBody, 'UTF-8', $parameters['charset']);
            } else {
                $messageBody = iconv($parameters['charset'], 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $messageBody);
            }
        }
        if (strtolower($structure->subtype) === 'plain' || ($structure->type == 1 && strtolower($structure->subtype) !== 'alternative')) {
            $this->plaintextMessage = '';
            $this->plaintextMessage .= trim(htmlentities($messageBody));
            $this->plaintextMessage = nl2br($this->plaintextMessage);
        } elseif (strtolower($structure->subtype) === 'html') {
            $this->htmlMessage = '';
            $this->htmlMessage .= $messageBody;
        }
    }
    if (isset($structure->parts)) {
        foreach ($structure->parts as $partIndex => $part) {
            $partId = $partIndex + 1;
            if (isset($partIdentifier))
                $partId = $partIdentifier . '.' . $partId;
            $this->processStructure($uid, $part, $partId);
        }
    }
}
private function setFileName($text) {
    $this->filename = $this->decode($text);
}
private function saveToDirectory($path, $uid, $partIdentifier) { //save attachments to directory
    $path = rtrim($path, '/') . '/';
    $full_file_place = $path . $this->filename;
    if (file_exists($path . $this->filename)) {
        $this->filename = time() . rand(1, 100) . $this->filename; // :)
    } elseif (!is_dir($path)) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Cant find directory for email attachments! Message ID:' . $uid;
        return false;
    } elseif (!is_writable($path)) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Attachments directory is not writable! Message ID:' . $uid;
        return false;
    }
    if (($filePointer = fopen($path . $this->filename, 'w')) == false) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Cant open file at imap class to save attachment file! Message ID:' . $uid;
        return false;
    }
    switch ($this->encoding) {
        case 3: //base64
            $streamFilter = stream_filter_append($filePointer, 'convert.base64-decode', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
            break;
        case 4: //quoted-printable
            $streamFilter = stream_filter_append($filePointer, 'convert.quoted-printable-decode', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);
            break;
        default:
            $streamFilter = null;
    }
    $result = imap_savebody($this->imapStream, $filePointer, $uid, $partIdentifier ? : 1, FT_UID);
    if ($streamFilter) {
        stream_filter_remove($streamFilter);
    }
    fclose($filePointer);
    return $result;
}
private function decodeMessage($data, $encoding) {
    if (!is_numeric($encoding)) {
        $encoding = strtolower($encoding);
    }
     switch ($encoding) {
              # 7BIT
              case 0:
                  return $data;
              # 8BIT
              case 1:
                  return quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($data));
              # BINARY
              case 2:
                  return imap_binary($data);
              # BASE64
              case 3:
                  return imap_base64($data);
              # QUOTED-PRINTABLE
              case 4:
                  return quoted_printable_decode($data);
              # OTHER
              case 5:
                  return $data;
              # UNKNOWN
              default:
                  return $data;
          }
}
private function getParametersFromStructure($structure) {
    $parameters = array();
    if (isset($structure->parameters))
        foreach ($structure->parameters as $parameter)
            $parameters[strtolower($parameter->attribute)] = $parameter->value;
    if (isset($structure->dparameters))
        foreach ($structure->dparameters as $parameter)
            $parameters[strtolower($parameter->attribute)] = $parameter->value;
    return $parameters;
}
private function getOverview($uid) {
    $results = imap_fetch_overview($this->imapStream, $uid, FT_UID);
    $messageOverview = array_shift($results);
    if (!isset($messageOverview->date)) {
        $messageOverview->date = null;
    }
    return $messageOverview;
}
private function decode($text) {
    if (null === $text) {
        return null;
    }
    $result = '';
    foreach (imap_mime_header_decode($text) as $word) {
        $ch = 'default' === $word->charset ? 'ascii' : $word->charset;
        $result .= iconv($ch, 'utf-8', $word->text);
    }
    return $result;
}
private function processAddressObject($addresses) {
    $outputAddresses = array();
    if (is_array($addresses))
        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            if (property_exists($address, 'mailbox') && $address->mailbox != 'undisclosed-recipients') {
                $currentAddress = array();
                $currentAddress['address'] = $address->mailbox . '@' . $address->host;
                if (isset($address->personal)) {
                    $currentAddress['name'] = $this->decode($address->personal);
                }
                $outputAddresses = $currentAddress;
            }
        }
    return $outputAddresses;
}
private function getHeaders($uid) {
    $rawHeaders = $this->getRawHeaders($uid);
    $headerObject = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($rawHeaders);
    if (isset($headerObject->date)) {
        $headerObject->udate = strtotime($headerObject->date);
    } else {
        $headerObject->date = null;
        $headerObject->udate = null;
    }
    $this->headers = $headerObject;
    return $this->headers;
}
private function getRawHeaders($uid) {
    $rawHeaders = imap_fetchheader($this->imapStream, $uid, FT_UID);
    return $rawHeaders;
}
private function getStructure($uid) {
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->imapStream, $uid, FT_UID);
    return $structure;
}
public function __destruct() {
    if (!empty($this->errors)) {
        foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
            //SAVE YOUR LOG OF ERRORS
        }
    }
}}?>
```

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: Please don't just post a ton of code and expect us to go through it all. Specially when it doesn't contain proper comments. Do some basic debugging and narrow down the issue.

Comment: What mailbox do you pass in `imap_open()` call ? Do you also check SPAM folder (not only INBOX) ?

Comment: In imap_open() am giving `'{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX'`. Am receiving mails but not body of mail. Its fetching empty content.